# Iterate Over a Dataframe as each time column is passing to do transformation

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 100 columns and col names like col1, col2, col3.... I want to apply certain transformation on the values of columns based on condition matches. I can store the column names in a array of string. And pass the value each element of the array in withColumn and based on When condition i can transform the values of the column vertically.
But the question is, as Dataframe is immutable, so each updated version is need to store in a new variable and also new dataframe need to pass in withColumn to transform for next iteration.
Is there any way to create array of dataframe so that new dataframe can be stored as a element of array and it can iterate based on the value of iterator.
Or is there any other way to handle the same.

```
var arr_df : Array[DataFrame] = new Array[DataFrame](60)
```

--> This throws error "not found type DataFrame"

```
val df(0) = df1.union(df2)

for(i <- 1 to 99){
  val df(i) = df(i-1).withColumn(col(i), when(col(i)> 0, col(i) + 
   1).otherwise(col(i)))
```

Here col(i) is an array of strings that stores the name of the columns of the original datframe .

As a example :

```
scala> val original_df = Seq((1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5),(3,4,5,6),(4,5,6,7),(5,6,7,8),(6,7,8,9)).toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4")
original_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> original_df.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|
|   2|   3|   4|   5|
|   3|   4|   5|   6|
|   4|   5|   6|   7|
|   5|   6|   7|   8|
|   6|   7|   8|   9|
+----+----+----+----+
```

I want to iterate 3 columns : col1, col2, col3 if the value of that column is greater than 3, then it will be updated by +1

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As the community standard, can you please post a sample input , what you have tried, expected output and where you are stuck?

Comment: @Raghu, Please let me know if you want me to more specific. I can not share the exact code but I will try give an example if needed

Comment: yes a sample input and an excpected output would help. Also try formating your code using the format option -{ when you edit. That improves readablity

Comment: @Raghu , Hope this helps you to understand the problem more specifically .

Comment: It would be good if you can add sample data, what kind of transformation and expected output..

Comment: Hi @Srinivas , updated the question. Please check . Hope this helps.

Comment: Check below I have added solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |4   |
|2   |3   |4   |5   |
|3   |4   |5   |6   |
|4   |5   |6   |7   |
|5   |6   |7   |8   |
|6   |7   |8   |9   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

```
scala>  val requiredColumns = df.columns.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 < 3).map(_._1).toSet
requiredColumns: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(col1, col2, col3)
```

```
scala> val allColumns = df.columns
allColumns: Array[String] = Array(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

```
scala> val columnExpr = allColumns.filterNot(requiredColumns(_)).map(col(_)) ++ requiredColumns.map(c => when(col(c) > 3, col(c) + 1).otherwise(col(c)).as(c))
```

```
scala> df.select(columnExpr:_*).show(false)
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |4   |
|2   |3   |5   |5   |
|3   |5   |6   |6   |
|5   |6   |7   |7   |
|6   |7   |8   |8   |
|7   |8   |9   |9   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: very helpful. Now out of 100 column 50 column need to mention in Seq() and rest 50 without any condition. That I need to find a way out.

Comment: yes, they are in sequence order like col1, col2, col3..... col30 to col79 i want to do the transformation .

Comment: I am getting below error in final statement in select API. If you know the reason, please let me know :

error: overloaded method value select with Alternatives:
[U1](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,UI]) org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[UI] <and> 
(col: String, cols:String*)org.apache.spark.DataFrame <and>
(cols*: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame cannot be applied to (object)

Comment: Sorry , that is not possible actually . :(

Comment: thanku very much. You save my day. it is not worked as map(col(_))(was saying for the fixed column that value is ambiguous ) but it is worked as map(lit(_)) . If you know can you please tell me what is the difference between "col" and "lit"

Comment: If you want to add ```static or constant``` values use ```lit```& to select columns use ```col```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are trying to do a dataframe wise operation. you dont need to iterate for this . I can show you how it can be done in pyspark. probably it can be taken over in scala.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,7,0),(1,8,4),(1,0,10),(5,1,90),(7,6,0),(0,3,11)],schema=['col1','col2','col3'])
expr = [F.when(F.col(coln)>3,F.col(coln)+1).otherwise(F.col(coln)).alias(coln) for coln in tst.columns if 'col3' not in coln]
tst1= tst.select(*expr)
```

results:

```
tst1.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   8|
|   1|   9|
|   1|   0|
|   6|   1|
|   8|   7|
|   0|   3|
+----+----+
```

This should give you the desired result

Comment: I do not want to iterate over all the columns. As a example of this, out 100 columns, I only iterate over 50 columns.

Comment: you  have the needed columns as a list? then you can use that list inside the list comprehension instead of tst.columns

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all columns and apply the condition in single line as below,

```
original_df.select(original_df.columns.map(c => (when(col(c) > lit(3), col(c)+1).otherwise(col(c))).alias(c)):_*).show()


+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   5|
|   2|   3|   5|   6|
|   3|   5|   6|   7|
|   5|   6|   7|   8|
|   6|   7|   8|   9|
|   7|   8|   9|  10|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: @Ayan Chatterjee, check this, its even sleek and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foldLeft` whenever you want to make changes on multiple `columns` as below

```
val original_df = Seq(
  (1,2,3,4),
  (2,3,4,5),
  (3,4,5,6),
  (4,5,6,7),
  (5,6,7,8),
  (6,7,8,9)
).toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4")

//Filter the columns that yuou want to update
val columns = original_df.columns

columns.foldLeft(original_df){(acc, colName) =>
  acc.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName) > 3, col(colName) + 1).otherwise(col(colName)))
}
.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |5   |
|2   |3   |5   |6   |
|3   |5   |6   |7   |
|5   |6   |7   |8   |
|6   |7   |8   |9   |
|7   |8   |9   |10  |
+----+----+----+----+
```